# JavaScript function in twig foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I have this code that has the phone number of different posters.

```
{% for ad in ads %}
...
    <a class="btn"  onclick="showNumber()" id="showNumber"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> View Phone Number</a>

    <input id="phonenum" style="display: none;" type="text" value="{{ ad.user.phone }}">
...
{% endfor %}
```

and the Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showNumber() {
  document.getElementById('showNumber').innerHTML = document.getElementById('phonenum').value;
}
</script>
```

the above works and the input field shows correctly the different numbers of the posters when i change it to block. But the problem is that  the phone number of the first button on the first button shows regardless of which button i click. what else should i do there?

Comment: Each button and input will get the same `id` so that will result in invalid HTML. Also don't use the `onclick` attribute but use `.addEventListener` in your js. Use classnames to get the right elements instead of ids

Answer (score 1):

IDs are meant to be unique, you're creating elements in a loop and giving them the same ID (`phonenum`), instead of IDs you should use class names and retrieve the appropriate element base on which anchor was clicked. Here is an example:

```
{% for ad in ads %}
...
    <a class="btn" onclick="showNumber(e)"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> View Phone Number</a>

    <input class="phonenum" style="display: none;" type="text" value="{{ ad.user.phone }}">
...
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showNumber(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML = e.target.parent.querySelector('.phonenum').value;
  }
</script>
```

In this example, `e.target` is the clicked anchor and I'm using `e.target.parent.querySelector('.phonenum')` to retrieve the input associated with the anchor (I'm assuming they have the same parent element).

Comment: I tried it but i am getting this error in console ````Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined````